# could not convert categorical data to number OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I have a simple code to convert categorical data into one hot encoding in python:

```
a,1,p
b,3,r
a,5,t
```

I tried to convert them with python OneHotEncoder:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\test.txt", sep=",", header=None)
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0,2])
one_hot_encoder.fit(data.values)
```

This piece of code does not work and throws an error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 't'
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: I upgraded to the sklearn 0.20 version and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

for c in df.columns:
    df[c]=df[c].apply(str)
    le=preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit(df[c])
    df[c] =le.transform(df[c])
    pd.to_numeric(df[c]).astype(np.float)
```

Answer (score 1):

@user3104352,

I encountered the same behavior and found it frustrating.

Scikit-Learn requires *all* data to be numerical before it even considers selecting the columns provided in the `categorical_features` parameter.

Specifically, the column selection is handled by the `_transform_selected()` method in /sklearn/preprocessing/data.py and the very first line of that method is

`X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)`.

This check fails if *any* of the data in the provided dataframe `X` cannot be successfully converted to a float.

I agree that the documentation of sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder is very misleading in that regard.